# Minimal Number of Polynomials to Determine a $2 \times 3$ Matrix up to Row Exchanges

Tags: polynomials, symmetric-polynomials

Suppose I have $2 \times 3$ matrix of real variables
$$ X=\begin{bmatrix} x_1 & y_1 & z_1 \\ x_2 & y_2 & z_2 \end{bmatrix}.$$

I am interested in finite sequences of polynomials $p_1(X), p_2(X),\dots p_N(X)$ (in the entries of $X$) that allow for recovering $X$ up to row exchanges (precisely). **In particular, I am looking for such sequences with the fewest terms $N_\text{min}$**.

**My attempt:**

A reasonable candidate is the elementary multisymmetric functions, which arise via expanding
$$(1+x_1 x+y_1 y+z_1 z)(1+x_2 x+y_2 y+z_2 z) =\sum_\alpha e_{\alpha}(X) x^{\alpha_1} y^{\alpha_2} z^{\alpha_2}.  $$
Specifically, we get
$$
\begin{align}
&1\\
&+(x_1+x_2) x+(y_1+y_2)y+(z_1+z_2)z \\
&+(x_1 x_2)x^2+(x_1 y_2+x_2 y_1) x y +(x_1 z_2+x_2 z_1) x z+(y_1 y_2) y^2+(y_1 z_2+y_2 z_1)yz+(z_1z_2)z^2,  
\end{align}$$
with $N=9$ elementary multisymmetric functions
$$\begin{align}
e_{(1,0,0)}&=x_1+x_2, \\
e_{(0,1,0)}&=y_1+y_2, \\
e_{(0,0,1)}&=z_1+z_2, \\ 
e_{(2,0,0)}&=x_1 x_2, \\
e_{(1,1,0)}&=x_1 y_2 + x_2 y_1, \\
e_{(1,0,1)}&= x_1 z_2+x_2 z_1, \\
e_{(0,2,0)}&=y_1 y_2, \\
e_{(0,1,1)}&=y_1 z_2+y_2 z_1, \\
e_{(0,0,2)}&= z_1 z_2.
\end{align} $$

I am hoping that $N=6$ polynomials suffice (i.e. the number of variables). Here is my reasoning:

In the $2 \times 2$ case, with

$$X=\begin{bmatrix} x_1 & y_1 \\ x_2 & y_2 \end{bmatrix}, $$
the elementary multisymmetric functions are

$$
\begin{align}
e_{(1,0)}&=x_1+x_2 ,\\
e_{(0,1)}&= y_1+y_2 ,\\
e_{(2,0)}&=x_1 x_2, \\
e_{(1,1)}&= x_1 y_2 +x_2 y_1, \\ 
e_{(0,2)}&= y_1 y_2,
\end{align}
$$
with $N=5$. However, expanding the complex polynomial
$$(Z-(x_1+y_1 i))(Z-(x_2+y_2 i)), $$
gives $N=4$ polynomials instead:
$$\begin{align}
&x_1+x_2 \\
&y_1+y_2 \\
&x_1 x_2-y_1 y_2 \\
&x_1 y_2+x_2 y_1
\end{align} $$
corresponding to the real and imaginary parts of the complex elementary symmetric polynomials $$e_1(x_1+y_1 i,x_2+y_2 i), \\ e_2(x_1+y_1i,x_2+y_2i).$$

I know that $n=2$ is different, in the sense that there is no 3-dimensional analogue of the field $\mathbf{C}$ over $\mathbf{R}$. Nevertheless, I couldn't rule out more efficient approaches than the elementary multisymmetric functions.

**Remark:**
This question is a subproblem of my question on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/392249/maximally-independent-polynomial-families-with-row-symmetry), dealing with the $m \times n$ case.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You seem to mean “polynomials of entries of $X$” instead of “polynomials of $X$” when writing $p(X)$. Is that true?

Comment: @Saad Correct. As if the matrix is flattened to a long vector.

Comment: By exactly so you mean by "recovering $X$" here?

Comment: @KBS That knowledge of the polynomials enables a map to get the rows of the matrix back, as an unordered set.

Comment: Do you mean : the knowledge of the polynomial evaluated at $X$ ? If so, your reasoning seems odd to me because you can simply choose $p_{i, j}(X) = X_{i, j}$ and you trivially get the (exact) knowledge of $X$ with $6$ polynomials here. (But maybe there is something I didn't understand ?)

Comment: @Rondoudou given your polynomial set, I can recover the entire matrix. I know that $p_{1,1}$ will always give me the upper-left corner entry etc. I'm looking for the smallest set of polynomials which allows me to get the matrix back, *up to any permutation of the rows*. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Oh, I got it by looking at MathOverflow. I meant that, if you have the exact knowledge of a matrix, you have in particular the knowledge of this matrix up to row permutations. Here you add the constraint that the polynomials have a "row-symmetry".

Answer (score 2):

The best known result for the $2 \times 3$ case is that $N_\text{min} = 8$, which can be achieved by using the Plücker coordinates of the matrix $X$.

It is also known that $N_\text{min} \leq 9$, with the elementary multisymmetric polynomials being a possible choice of polynomials.

As for your approach using complex numbers, it is indeed possible to do better than the elementary multisymmetric polynomials in the $2 \times 2$ case. However, this is not possible in the $2 \times 3$ case, as the Plücker coordinates already give a set of 8 polynomials that are algebraically independent over $\mathbf{C}$. (In fact, it is known that the Plücker coordinates are algebraically independent over $\mathbf{R}$ as well.)

Thus, your approach using complex numbers cannot give a set of polynomials with fewer than 8 terms.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would you mind writing the eight Plücker polynomials explicitly?